# QOSAddSocketToFlow returns error - ELEMENT NOT FOUND

Tags: winapi, networking, packets

I am working with QWAVE API to set DSCP value in packets.

I am trying to do multiple calls with DSCP bit set as 46 between server and client.

For each call I have to add socket to the QOS flow which is done by `QOSAddSocketToFlow`.

Problem arises when DSCP bit for some of the calls were not getting set correctly.

Further I found that for those calls `QOSAddSocketToFlow` API is returning an error code:

> Element Not Found

This error is no where specified as possible return code on the [MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374027(v=vs.85).aspx).

I am using `QOS_NON_ADAPTIVE_FLOW` and traffic type as `QOSTrafficTypeBestEffort`

```
QoSResult = QOSAddSocketToFlow(
     QoSHandle,
     ConnectSocket,
     sockaddr,
     QOSTrafficTypeExcellentEffort, 
      QOS_NON_ADAPTIVE_FLOW, 
     &FlowId);
```

I want to understand in what scenario `QOSAddSocketToFlow` can throw this error code. Also, this is not happening for all calls, some random calls are getting this error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some code to help other people to reproduce your problem.

Comment: We cannot see your code. Post a [mcve] so we don't have to guess. Besides, if you read the documentation for [QOSAddSocketToFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374027.aspx) carefully, you'll see that it explicitly points out, that the table shows *"**some** possible error codes"*. Your code needs to be prepared to handle other error codes as well.

Comment: Updated the question with more information. @IInspectable

Comment: *"this is not happening for all calls, some random calls are getting this error"* - That's a pretty good indication, that there is a bug in your code. Code, we cannot see. Unless you provide a [mcve], this question isn't useful, and will be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think my team has figured this out.

We're using the QWave API in C# with a custom-written pinvoke library in order for us to test DSCP-style QOS on unicast udp, unicast tcp, and multicast udp sockets, and we too started seeing ELEMENT_NOT_FOUND errors from QosAddSocketToFlow.

QosAddSocketToFlow would work most of the time, but in some instances, we got the error.

Turns out that QosAddSocketToFlow requires that you bind the socket first, either to a real source address or to INADDR_ANY.

In our broken code, we were adding to qos first:

```
if( this.dscpCodePoint != null && this.dscpCodePoint > 0 )
{
    ApplyQosCodePoint( this.dscpCodePoint.Value );
}

this.socket.Bind( new IPEndPoint( this.sourceAddress, this.sourcePort ) );
```

And while this usually worked, it would frequently cause multicast sockets to throw the ELEMENT_NOT_FOUND error. We simply switched the order of the statements and the error went away:

```
this.socket.Bind( new IPEndPoint( this.sourceAddress, this.sourcePort ) );

if( this.dscpCodePoint != null && this.dscpCodePoint > 0 )
{
    ApplyQosCodePoint( this.dscpCodePoint.Value );
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to share the pinvoke code used in ApplyQosCodePoint? :)